# Problemas de conexion en Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

ME sale el siguiente error quiero conectar con sql,pero nada.
error:

> 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' Check that mysqld is running and
>   that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías asegurarte de que el servicio mysql está levantado, prueba a iniciar el servicio de la siguiente manera desde una terminal:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 1):

L.Bar5522:

Este error podría darse por varias situaciones.

1. ¿Tienes instalado el servidor? Podrías comprobarlo con el comando `dpkg --get-selections` Por ejemplo,con MySQL sería lo siguiente:

```
$ -> dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
libdbd-mysql-perl               install
libmysqlclient20:amd64              install
mysql-client-core-5.7               install
mysql-common                    install
```

En este caso, no tengo el servidor instalado, solamente el cliente. Por lo que en este caso no tengo el servicio corriendo en local y no podré realizar ninguna conexión:

```
$ -> mysql -u root 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Si no tienes el servicio instalado podrías hacerlo con apt-get install, por ejemplo:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install mysql-server
```

2. En caso de tener el servicio instalado, lo siguiente es verificar que esté levantado el servicio:

```
service mysqld status
```

Si no está running, podrías levantar el servicio con:

```
service mysqld start
```

3. Podrías ver el socket en el que se encuentra la ruta ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq ) y verificar que esté correcta.

Podrías proporcionar un poco más de información y si es posible, ejecutar los comandos anteriores para poder revisar con mayor exactitud cuál podría ser la causa del problema.

Comment: Sí tengo instalado el server pero al hacer status me da un error nuevo,**unit mysqld status could not by found** Qué puedo hacer??Estoy trabajando con mysql workbench,y al intentar hacer un forward engineer me da error y me dice en session que no hay conexion establecida

Comment: ¿Podrías apuntarnos la salida del siguiente comando?
dpkg --get-selections | grep 'mysql\|mariadb'

Comment: Lo acabo de solucionar reiniciar y start mysql,eso sí con sudo delante y sin la d.Muchisimas gracias ni mis profesores eran capaces de resolverlo!!

Comment: Me alegro, cualquier duda puedes consultarlo sin problema. Si la respuesta te ha servido de ayuda puedes marcarla. Saludos.